# POST, PUT and DELETE methods won't work in my web application

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm building small web app with angularJS and Web Api. I've created backend and everything worked fine while I was testing with postman. But now i just can't make it work from my frontend, al least not for POST;PUT and DELETE methods.
I've tried everything, no I'm bit desperate.

This is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using PlaylistWebApi.Models;
using PlaylistWebApi.Services;

namespace PlaylistWebApi.Controllers
{
    public class SongsController : ApiController
    {

        private readonly ISongService _service;

        public SongsController(ISongService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Song> Get()
        {
            IEnumerable<Song> items = null;
            try
            {
                items = _service.GetAll();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var message = string.Format("Error while retrieving songs!");
                throw new HttpResponseException(
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, message));
            }

            return items;

        }

        public Song Get(int id)
        {
            Song item = null;
            try
            {
                item = _service.Get(id);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var message = string.Format("Error while retrieving the song!");
                throw new HttpResponseException(
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, message));
            }

            if (item == null)
            {
                var message = string.Format("Error while retriving song!");
                throw new HttpResponseException(
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message));
            }
            else
            {
                return item;
            }
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpOptions,HttpPost]
        public Song Post([FromBody]Song song)
        {
            Song item = null;
            try
            {
                item = _service.Add(song);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var message = string.Format("Error while adding new song!");
                throw new HttpResponseException(
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, message));
            }
            return item;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpOptions,HttpPut]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]Song item)
        {
            try
            {
                _service.Update(item);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var message = string.Format("Error while editing song!");
                throw new HttpResponseException(
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, message));
            }
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpOptions,HttpDelete]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                _service.Remove(id);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var message = string.Format("Error while removing song!");
                throw new HttpResponseException(
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, message));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my fronted callback

```
playlistService.service('dataService', ['$http', function ($http) {

        var urlBase = 'http://localhost:9000/api';

     this.getSongs= function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase+ '/songs');
    };


    this.getSong = function (id) {
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/songs/' + id);
    };

    this.insertSong = function (song) {
        return $http.post(urlBase+ '/songs/', song);
    };

    this.updateSong = function (song) {
        return $http.put(urlBase+'/songs/'+ song.ID , song);
    };

    this.deleteSong = function (id) {
        return $http.delete(urlBase + '/songs/' + id);
    };

}]);
```

Error for Delete method

```
Remote Address:[::1]:9000
Request URL:http: //localhost:9000/api/songs/5
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:2236
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 03 Jul 2015 00:22:25 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RDpccmVwb3NpdG9yeVxQbGF5bGlzdFdlYkFwaVxQbGF5bGlzdFdlYkFwaVxhcGlcc29uZ3NcNQ==?=
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:DELETE
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http: //127.0.0.1:50119
Referer:http: //127.0.0.1:50119/index.html



Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction, Exception=System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
Put on type PlaylistWebApi.Controllers.SongsController
delete on type PlaylistWebApi.Controllers.SongsController
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction>b__0()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : Operation=SongsController.ExecuteAsync, Exception=System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
Put on type PlaylistWebApi.Controllers.SongsController
delete on type PlaylistWebApi.Controllers.SongsController
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction>b__0()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=500 (InternalServerError), Method=OPTIONS, Url=http: //localhost:9000/api/songs/5, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=SongsController.Dispose
```

For POST an PUT I don't get any error, it redirects me back to the same from with strange uri(object which I am posting). What I'm doing wrong?

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3 class="page-header"><i class="fa fa-plus "></i> Songs</h3>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><i class="icon_mic_alt"></i>Songs</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-plus "></i>Add New</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
      <!-- Form validations -->              
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
              <section class="panel">
                  <header class="panel-heading">
                      Add New Song
                  </header>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-validate form-horizontal " id="register_form" method="get" action="">
                             <div class="alert alert-block"  >
                                    <div ng-repeat="alert in alerts"  type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">
                                        <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close close-sm" type="button" >{{alert.msg}}>
                                            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                                    </button> 
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="songname" class="control-label col-lg-2">Song name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                                      <input class="form-control" id="songname" name="songname" ng-model="songName" type="text" />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="filename" class="control-label col-lg-2">File Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                                      <input class="form-control" id="filename" name="filename" ng-model="fileName" type="text" />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="artistname" class="control-label col-lg-2">Username <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                                      <input class="form-control" id="artistname" name="artistname" ng-model="artistName" type="text" />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="album" class="control-label col-lg-2">Album</label>
                                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                                      <input class="form-control" id="album" name="album"  ng-model="album" type="text" />
                                  </div>
                             </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addSong()">Save</button>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </form>
                      </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: How are you triggering this from the view template? And what does the network headers look like when you perform the DELETE?

Comment: @Jasen Yes, that's what happening when I trigger DELETE from my view template.

Comment: OPTIONS /api/songs/5 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:50119
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:50119/index.html?songname=erger&filename=eerer&artistname=egr&album=gege
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: That is request header

Comment: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpccmVwb3NpdG9yeVxQbGF5bGlzdFdlYkFwaVxQbGF5bGlzdFdlYkFwaVxhcGlcc29uZ3NcNQ==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Date: Fri, 03 Jul 2015 01:27:07 GMT
Content-Length: 2236

Comment: I think you should remove `[HttpOptions]` from your actions and make a dedicated `Options()` action. You error is telling you it can't resolve multiple matching routes and its trying to match every action marked with `[HttpOptions]` because the request verb is OPTIONS.

Comment: OPTIONS request made because your client app is on a different domain with the api. You should remove HttpOptions on POST/PUT/DELETE method, try again and tell us what is the new result :)

Comment: Ok this fixed my Delete method but ,put and post after pre-flighted CORS still don't work. My Options method looks like this... public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    return response;
}

Comment: OPTIONS /api/songs/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:50916
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:50916/index.html?songname=C1dfdsfs&filename=C.mp3&artistname=A&album=A
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpccmVwb3NpdG9yeVxQbGF5bGlzdFdlYkFwaVxQbGF5bGlzdFdlYkFwaVxhcGlcc29uZ3Nc?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 03 Jul 2015 15:39:35 GMT
Content-Length: 0

Comment: OK i now see that my when i call POST method my refer method is odd        OPTIONS /api/songs/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:50916
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:50916/index.html?songname=C1&filename=C.mp3&artistname=A&album=rrr
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: Basically after OPTIONS method get method is call with json daza as query string... so anoying :(

Comment: `it redirects me back to the same from with strange uri(object which I am posting)` What does your template look like? Is there a form and are you preventing the standard form submission?

Comment: I love u  man :D I  see it now.. I copied free template and I didn't even look what is on form :) and yes u solved my initial problem your solution , adding dedicated Options() action, worked.  :) how can i accept it ? I'll buy you set for your favorite Dota 2 Hero :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems here. First, you have the exception with the OPTIONS request.

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
  Put on type PlaylistWebApi.Controllers.SongsController
  delete on type PlaylistWebApi.Controllers.SongsController
```

Remove `HttpOptions` from your other actions and make a dedicated endpoint.

```
[HttpOptions]
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
}
```

Next, you have the redirection back to the form with the strange url which indicates you may have allowed the standard form submission. Angular will take care of this for you -- just remove the `action` parameter and specify `ng-submit`. Don't forget to remove `ng-click` from the button.

```
<form id="register_form" ng-submit="addSong()">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

From [ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit):

> Enables binding angular expressions to onsubmit events.
>
> Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), but only if the form does not contain action, data-action, or x-action attributes.